Local linear kernel regression
It is know that the prediction for a given point $x$ is given by:
$$\hat{f}_h(x) = \hat{\beta}_0(x)$$
where
$$\hat{\beta}(x) = \arg\min_{\beta_0, \beta_1}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac{x - x_i}{h}\right)(Y_i - \beta_0  - \beta_1(x_i - x))^2.$$
I intuitively understood why, for the prediction, we just consider the intercept: the local linear model is regressing over the distances between the $x_i$s and $x$, so makes sense that for the prediction we consider the value of the regression line for distance equal to 0.
What I do not understand is the following, why don't we just solve this problem instead (which is the one I first thought when I approached this topic)?
$$\hat{f}_h(x) = \hat{\beta}_0(x) + \hat{\beta_1}(x)x$$
where
$$\hat{\beta}(x) = \arg\min_{\beta_0, \beta_1}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac{x - x_i}{h}\right)(Y_i - \beta_0  - \beta_1x_i)^2.$$
So instead of regressing over the distances we just do local regression over the single points, but then we use all the regression line to make the prediction.
Is this approach wrong? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.
